# FTP User Permissions

Tags: apache, ftp, centos, chmod

I have a CentOS server and I want to know if it is possible to give to the ftp user permissions "over" the Apache user? Because if I create a folder with Apache (with 755 rights), I can't remove it from ftp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add FTP user to the same group as your Apache user.
For example, if your Apache user in the `apache` group (default in CentOS) run:
`sudo useradd -G apache ftp_username`